# Why is the Legendre polynomials eigenfunctions to this operator?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, legendre-polynomials

The operator $$Au = -\frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)\frac{du}{dx}), \quad -1<x<1$$
supposedly has eigenfunctions
$$P_0 = 1, \quad P_1 = x, \quad P_2 = \frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x$$
with eigenvalues
$$\lambda_0 = 0, \quad \lambda_1 = 2, \quad \lambda_2 = 6.$$

Controlling this, the first two are ok, but the third one seems wrong,

$$AP_2 = -((1-x^2)(3x-\frac{1}{2}))' = -(3x-3x^3-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2})' = (-3+9x^2 -x) \neq \lambda_2\frac{3}{2}x^2 - \lambda_2\frac{1}{2}x \implies AP_2 \neq \lambda_2P_2.$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sanity check: The Legendre polynomials have the same parity as their degree. In particular, the second Legendre polynomial should be an even function (i.e., only contain even powers of $x$). But your $P_2(x)$ is not even, and so cannot be correct.

Comment: ?? I don't understand, wikipedia specifically states that that is a legendre polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Rodrigues'_formula_and_other_explicit_formulas

Right after "The first few Legendre polynomials are:" there is a table which contains $P_2$. What is going on here?

Comment: Read their table more carefully, keeping in mind that $P_2$ must have even parity.

Comment: Thanks, my attention to detail is on the same level as a gorilla on meth. Sorry

Comment: This is the purpose of a sanity check, to be clear: Even without computing inner products, the presence of both $x$ and $x^2$ meant that your $P_2$ couldn't be correct. Another check is that $P_n(1)=1$. Both of these are necessary (not sufficient) conditions for a proposed $P_n(x)$ to be correct. (Your $P_2$ actually passes this second condition. So eventually all one can do is either check a table more carefully or start computing inner products.)